# How do I properly add a SQL Server connection string as a systemd environment variable for asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, systemd

So I am having this problem, where I have a ASP.NET Core application that seems to work fine, when just doing dotnet program.dll

It reads the values it should from the appsettings.json
For obvious reasons however, this isn't feasible in the production environment, where several such services should run side by side, each with its own systemd *.service file. Thus; environment variables.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which clearly shows the connectionstring should be put as:

```
Environment=SQLCONNSTR_key={escaped connstring}
```

My Procedure to do this is as follows:

1. Escape the connectionstring:

`connstr=$(systemd-escape 'Server=tcp:something.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=some-database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=some_database_user;Password=$pec!al#OfCh@rs;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;')`

2. copy the value of `echo $connstr` into `Environment=SQLCONNSTR_SqlServer={right-here-no-brackets}`
3. start the service: `sudo systemctl start <servicename>`

but it fails with this message:

`Failed to start bygbook-test.service: Unit bygbook-test.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status bygbook-test.service' for details.`

when i check the journal: `sudo journalctl -u <servicename>` I notice this exception:

`Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: ''server'.`

I honestly have no idea what is going wrong here, am I not doing this the way it's supposed to be done? am i forgetting something?

Comment: Maybe the port number is wrong.  You may have more than one instance of the database using different port numbers.  Try from cmd.exe > Netstat -a and see if a server is listening on port 1433.

Comment: I'm not familiar with netstat (know it exists, but i have never used it before) The port should be open however, as it's an azure Sqlaas with the IP of the server running the app open. As i stated, it runs just fine if i run it with `dotnet <name>.dll`

Comment: What Port Number?????  "SHOULD" is not a good assumption.  Lets prove it is opened.  Netstat should give more info.

Comment: If I can use the program, when I run it directly instead of under a service, the port IS open. Thus it is proved, netstat or not. There is database access. But there's something wrong with the systemd service file.

Comment: by the way, that was port number 1433 (standard for (MS)Sql Server

Comment: As you can see in your error log its showing you sinqle quote twice, which indicates that the connection string is not correctly escaped, due to which, it's breaking and only picking till server. I am not sure what could have made it not work while generating it, but going through the article which you have given link for, it usage double quotes rather then single quote.

Comment: using double quotes makes absolutely no difference, sadly. I'm totally at a loss here, I can not spot a single wrong character in the string...